# Error calling the a Livewire component when using Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection

Tags: collections, laravel-livewire

I have, the following Livewire component:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Pages;

use App\Models\Negotiation;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Livewire\Component;

class NeC extends Component
{
    public Negotiation $negotiation;

    public Collection $logs;

    public function mount(Negotiation $negotiation)
    {
        $this->negotiation = $negotiation;
    }

    public function render(): Factory|View|Application
    {
        $this->logs = $this->negotiation?->readL();
        return view('livewire.pages.ne-c');
    }
}
```

that works fine, but if I change

> use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

for

> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

I receive the error:

**Call to undefined method stdClass::getKey()**

when calling the component:

```
@livewire('pages.ne-c', ['negotiation' => $page->negotiation])
```

I could not find anything about this error out there. Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much.

**MOTIVATION OF THE PREVIOUS QUESTION:**

The reason that made me raise this question is that I am trying to find a way in Livewire to keep properties added to a model between Livewire updates. For example, I have this code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Works;

use App\Models\Work;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

class Indexes extends Component
{
public Collection $worksMaster;

public function mount()
{
    $this->worksMaster = Work::all();

    $this->worksMaster = $this->worksMaster->map(function ($item) {
        $item->status = $item->status();
        return $item;
    });

    $this->filter('ALL');
}

public function filter($filter)
{
    ...
    if($this->worksMaster->first()->status) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

public function render()
{
    return <<<'HTML'
        ...
        <span type="button" wire:click="filter('NEW')" ...
        ...
    HTML;
}
```

}

In this example, the first time that I call the component, in **mount()** I calculate and load the status in a property, so then, when I need to use it in **filter()** I do not need to calculate it again.

This goes fine the first time that I reach **filter()** from **mount()**, but when I call **filter()** from the HTML button, the field status is not present any more: I only find the fields of model Work (I suppose because the Livewire rehydration takes as a reference the Work model).

I want to avoid having to recalculate the status on each Livewire update. I have made a really dirty turnaround to solve it, but I would like to find something more robust and elegant.

Help is welcome! Thanks to all

Comment: 1. Why do you want to specifically define an Eloquent Collection? It extends the normal Collection.  
2. What does `readL()` do?

Comment: Livewire cannot rehydrate correctly collections of type Illuminate\Support\Collection (ISC), they need to be of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection (IDEC). readL() returns a Collection (which I manually  cast to ISC or IDEC for testing purposes, to make it match with the "use" that I am setting above)

Comment: Yes, you're right that Livewire cannot rehydrate an ISC, but it *can* rehydrate an IDEC. However, if you cast it as ISC but pass it an IDEC, it will work. I've always done it like that. If you cast something as Model, but pass it a `Post extends Model`, the rehydration will still give you your Post model.

Comment: Thank you very much Yinci! I will take it into account.

Comment: Hi Yinci, one question. Do you know any way to preserve a calculated field added (f.e. with ->map()) in the component to a model, between rehydrations?

Comment: I'll require the code or something such as a codepen to be able to make an educated suggestion on what needs to happen and how to solve it

Comment: Hi Yinci, I have updated the question to give you more references about my question

Comment: How "heavy" is the `status()` callback, that you don't use an `$appends`? (You can use `$appends` with an attribute getter to always have the value available on your model, see [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json))

Comment: It is enough heavy to use a dirty turnaround if it is the only way :-)

Comment: Then I can only suggest using a [computed property](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#computed-properties) with cache.

Comment: From the documentation: Computed properties are only cached for a single request
It's a common misconception that Livewire caches computed properties for the entire lifespan of your Livewire component on a page. However, this isn't the case. Instead, Livewire only caches the result for the duration of a single component request. This means that if your computed property method contains an expensive database query, it will be executed every time your Livewire component performs an update.... How could I cache thecomputed property?

Comment: By manually caching your result and returning it from the computed property. The other obvious way would be store the status in your database, but I assume you haven't done that for good reason.

Comment: Thank you Yinci. I will check how to manually cache, that seems more elegant. My dirty solution is like a manual cache, storing the statuses in an array (that has no problem with the Livewire cicles) and remap it in the Collection, but from the array (memory) instead of recalculating.